# How do I avoid repeated ajax calls when sharing data source between 2 Kendo grids

Tags: ajax, kendo-grid

I have 2 kendo grids that use the same data source. One displays zero balance orders and the other displays orders with balances > 0. Each one makes the same ajax call to get the full list of data and then applies a filter for the grid (0, >0). Is there a way to have both grids use the same datasource, but only make the ajax call once?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerOrder>()
    .Name("Orders")
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource   
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("OrderListAjax", controller))
        .PageSize(Constants.PageSize)
        .Filter(filters => { filters.Add(c => c.CurrentOrderBalance).IsGreaterThan(0); })
        )
```

...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerOrder>()
    .Name("ZeroBalanceOrders")
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("onZBdataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource   
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("OrderListAjax", controller))
        .PageSize(Constants.PageSize)
        .Filter(filters => { filters.Add(c => c.CurrentOrderBalance).IsEqualTo(0); })
        )
    .AutoBind(false)
```

Both grids make the same call to OrderListAjax and then filter. I would like to make the call once to retrieve the data and then apply the filter for each grid.